# Increase fields until exists. MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue and solution by creating deltas and update DB but maybe someone have another solution more convenient? All the time when i update or create item i should recount field `place`.

There is collection `posts`:

```
{pid: '1'}
{pid: '2'}
{pid: '3'}
{pid: '4'}
```

I update this collection and add new field:

```
{pid: '1'}
{pid: '2', place: 3}
{pid: '3'}
{pid: '4'}
```

And one more time

```
{pid: '1'}
{pid: '2', place: 3}
{pid: '3'}
{pid: '4', place: 5}
```

If if do it by row for example put place: 1 after place: 2 ... This work perfect and when i update or so it will work ok. but if i do it randomly i have a problem like:

I want in collection above, update pid: 3 and put place: 1 i will receive

```
{pid: '3', place: 1}
{pid: '1'}
{pid: '2', place: 4}
{pid: '4', place: 6}
```

place 3 -> place 4 and place 5 -> place 6. I use $inc and $gte/$lte regarding conditions. One of requests:

```
const recahnage = await modelPost.updateMany(
                        {
                            place: {
                                $gte: place
                            },
                            categories: {
                                $in: categories
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $inc: {
                                place: 1
                            }
                        })
```

In this situation I do not need increase place: 3 and place: 5 because place: 2 doesn't exists. I want stop increasing if place is not exists.

Does someone have an ideas? I do not want make delta and put `place` field right away in all items.

Comment: Are you saying you tried to update the `{pid: 3}` document and it also updated two other documents? Why is that? What update did you run exactly?

Comment: I have added requests in post above. But it is one of requests, regarding conditions i use $gte/$lte. But it is not important here. I use UpdateMany for increace `place` field.